# How to replace part of my text field in MySQL that has variable number appended

Tags: mysql, regex, text, replace, field

I have some text in a field that I need to replace, but the issue is it has a number ID appended to it, which I need to remove and replace with my value in my MySQL Trigger.

My field is like this:

```
[["Randomthinghere","anotherranodm4234","pitahayas","apples","bananas","apricots","grapes","kiwifruit"],["ACRE_PRC119_ID_9","randomthing","randomthing2"]]
```

And the value I need to replace ACRE_PRC119_ID_9 with is ACRE_PRC119, however its not always ID_9, it can be any reasonably small number value.

I've searched all over and read through manuals, and I'm honestly not sure what solution there is, if any in MySQL because I can't apply wildcard to replace.
If any solution requires REGEXP I could do something like REGEXP `^.*[[.".]]ACRE[[._.]]PRC119[[._.]]ID[[._.]]{[0-9]{1,9}}.*$';` sadly you can't capture the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go

```
set @var:='[["Randomthinghere","anotherranodm4234","pitahayas","apples","bananas","apricots","grapes","kiwifruit"],["ACRE_PRC119_ID_9"]]';
select concat(substring(@var,1,locate('ID_',@var)-2),'"]]') ;
```

Comment: I need it to be generic which is the problem, I need it to look through my column then find ACRE_PRC119_ID_* and replace it with ACRE_PRC119 when triggered in MySQL.

Comment: Is ACRE_PRC119_ID available in each row? What did you mean by generic?

Comment: ACRE_PRC119_ID_* may be available in each row, but there are also other values with ID_ in the name, ex: ACRE_PRC117F_ID_*, ACRE_PRC148_ID_*, this is hard to explain but what I am trying to do is search the rows for ACRE_PRC119_ID_* or other and then remove the _ID_* part by replacing it with ACRE_PRC119 or other after being triggered with a MySQL trigger.

Comment: Although not quite what I wanted, it gave me some insight into concat, I found http://techras.wordpress.com/2011/06/02/regex-replace-for-mysql which solves my problem.